# What does 'lymphatic aid' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In The Invisible Man,

> "...Millie, her ***lymphatic aid***, had been brisked up a bit by a few deftly chosen expressions of contempt..."

[Learner's dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/lymphatic) defines *lymphatic* as an adjective of *lymph* which is itself only defined as a medical term only.

What does the ***lymphatic aid*** mean?

Comment: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lymphatic) gives another possible meaning that might fit: _(of persons) having the characteristics, as flabbiness or sluggishness, formerly believed to be due to an excess of lymph in the system._

Comment: **lymphatic**, not **lymphatics**. The meaning would be roughly the opposite of **brisk**.  Please do not cease efforts after consulting only one dictionary. There are quite a few decent online dictionaries. When trying to understand a novel, a learner's dictionary is not likely to get you very far.

Comment: Is there not a comma between "maid" and "had", to balance the one at the beginning of the appositive phrase?

Comment: @shoover, I checked the source, and (of course) there is such a comma.  Also, the servant is not a maid - the servant turns out to be an aid.  I put in the edits.

Answer (score 2):

As @orekelens states in the comments, and confirmed also by Free Dictionary, **Lymphatic** is an [archaic word for](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lymphatic)

> Lacking energy or vitality; sluggish.

The [origin of the word](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lymphatic) comes from

> 1640s, from Modern Latin lymphaticus "pertaining to the lymph," from Latin lympha (see [lymph](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lymph)). The English word also sometimes is used in what was the primary sense of lymphaticus in classical Latin, "mad, frenzied." OED reports this meaning "difficult to account for," but perhaps due to association of lympha with nymphe; compare Greek nymphian "to be frenzy-stricken." Also sometimes in reference to the appearance or temperament of one thought to suffer from excess of lymph, "dull, sluggish, slow in thought or action, with flabby muscles and pale skin" (1834).

[Schmoop](http://www.shmoop.com/invisible-man-wells/power-quotes.html) talks about the passage quoted from *The Invisible Man* by saying

> Here, Mrs. Hall wants Millie to speed up her work. How does she do this?: "by a few deftly chosen expressions of contempt."